# i m working on panda when i am concating the data frame the i am getting module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
india_weather=pd.dataFrame({"city": ["mumbai","pratagarh","bangalore"],
                            "tempearature": [25,35,45],
                            "humidity": [56,78,80]})
india_weather
```

error i am getting
 module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataFrame'`enter code here`

Comment: You need  `pd.DataFrame` instread of `pd.data`

Comment: Please stop abusing and spamming the tags. The tags are important because it helps filtering the questions. This question does not have anything to do with java or mysql or C.

Comment: Capitalization matters in python

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pd.DataFrame` instead of `pd.dataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
india_weather=pd.DataFrame({"city": ["mumbai","pratagarh","bangalore"],
                            "tempearature": [25,35,45],
                            "humidity": [56,78,80]})
print(india_weather)
```

Output:

```
        city  tempearature  humidity
0     mumbai            25        56
1  pratagarh            35        78
2  bangalore            45        80
```